# Sequence of random variables with finite variance

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider a sequence of random variables $\{ X_k \}$ with variances $\mathrm{Var}(X_k) = k, ~ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. Can I say that the sequence $\{ X_k \}$ consist of random variables with finite variance (and hence finite expectation)?

Or only sequences like $\{Y_k\}, \, \mathrm{Var}(Y_k) \le c = \mathrm{const}, \, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ consist of random variables with finite variance?

I know that this is a stupid question and I should find an answer in books on the mathematical analysis and I tried this but found nothing.

Comment: If $\mathrm{Var}(X_k)=k$, then yes, each $X_k$ has a finite variance. The stronger condition $\sup_k\mathrm{Var}(X_k)<\infty$ would mean that the sequence is uniformly bounded in $L^2$.